# Updating the other column when data in the column changes in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, trigger

In ArcGIS in one of my layers, I combined two columns with calculated field and printed it into a third column. However when I change a data in my first column, I want that data in the third column to change automatically.

Is this possible?

How can this be done with Python code?

[image]

Comment: I want it to change automatically.

Comment: No, it's probably not possible (there is no automator to implement "automatic" unless the data is in a SQL database). Yet since you are changing one column, it's trivially easy to update two in a DA Cursor.

Comment: thanks for answer Vince,I just gave a column just to be an example. Normally it will take a long time to do it in the DA Cursor, as more than one column will change. Well, when the data is used as sql, we would have to write triggers on them.Right?

Comment: "Long time", as in a fraction of a millisecond? I regularly populate millions of rows with DA Cursors; the difference between one and two columns is often not measurable. "Automatic" processes aren't -- there's always some work in automation.

Comment: Could you explain how I can do this?

Comment: The documentation already covers this. You'd need to try, and provide your code, and a description of what went wrong before this would be on-topic in GIS SE. If the data is in an RDBMS, the writing a trigger would be researched in [dba.se].

Comment: Do you have access to ArcPro? There are Attribute Rules in Pro.

Comment: ArcMap also has the Attribute Assistant addin that is available as part of the ArcGIS Solutions. https://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/